# Button hover doesnt do anything

Tags: html, css, hover

I have these hover effects set up and it doesn't seem to be changing a thing. I can't figure out why.

Same thing happens with the primary button at the bottom.

```css
body { background-color: #aaa }

.button {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #1c1c1c;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button-primary {
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.button-primary:hover {
  background: #1c1c1c;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.button-down {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
}

.button-down:hover {
  background: white;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  border: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="down">
    <button class='button-down'><i class='fas fa-arrow-down'></i></button>
  </div>

  <input type="text" name='email' id='email' placeholder='signup to our newsletter...'>
  <br>
  <button class='button-primary' type='submit' name='submit'>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: where is button class? .button remove . from it and try again

Comment: Your styling the button class `.button`, not  the button tag `button`.

Comment: I have added the css with .button-down and it still isn't working, none of the hovers on the page are working

Comment: Please delete the question - voting to close as the issue is _caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0):

You linked your stylesheet to your html? 
Also, .button-down class in is not declared in css  but instead you have .button
Replace .button with .button-down and try again.

```
.button-down{
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
.button-down:hover{
    background: #1c1c1c;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```